# multiple git folders in parent and chidren folders

Tags: git, branch

I have `.git` folders in parent and every children folders. Is that expected ?
Can I delete the `.git` folders from inside the children folders and only keep the one inside the parent folder?

I do not see the branches under the parent folder
`git branch -a` returns blank
I do see them in one of the children folders.

How do I clean this up and see all the local and remote branches from the parent folder ?

Can i just delete all the .git folders and `git init` inside the parent folder? Would I then see the branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have .git folders in parent and every children folders. Is that expected ?

No: it means there was a `git init .` executed in each folders.

> Can I just delete all the .git folders and git init inside the parent folder? Would I then see the branches?

You won't see any branch just after a `git init .`, you would still have to do a `git add .` and a `git commit` to see *one* branch (`master` or `main`)

Comment: thanks would i be able to see the remote branches as well ?

Comment: @uniXVanXcel Not before you add a remote (`git remote add origin /url/to/remote/repo`) and fetch (`git fetch`): then a `git branch -avv` would show remote branches as well.

Comment: ok i will delete those extra .git folders in the children and run the commands in the parent. thanks !. will try and revert back to you